# button is made by datatables runs event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

and then when I click button or tag in datatables, open the modal twice and ajax runs twice.

ps. I use angular.js so datatables is directive. but datatables is not angular datatables moudule. directive is made by jquery datatables.

how do I resolve this problem?

Thank your answer.

this is my source.

1.datatable column render

```
/**
 * datatable
 */
$scope.grid = {};
$scope.grid.dtInstance = {};
$scope.grid.dtColumns = {
  columnDefs: [
    {
      "targets": 1,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        var return_value = siteInfo[row.site_code].name+"<br>"+row.site_id;
        return return_value;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 2,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.order_code;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 3,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return commonSVC.getDate(row.wdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 4,
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
        return row.status;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 5,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.prod_code;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 6,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.delivery_vendor;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 7,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.order_name;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 8,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.to_name;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 9,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.to_address;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 10,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.count;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 11,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.price;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 12,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return row.deli_cost;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 13,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        var return_value = row.deli_corp+"<br>"+row.deli_invoice;
        return return_value;
      }
    },
    {
      "targets": 14,
      "render": function (data, type, row) {
        var type = "shipment";
        var toDeleteStr = row.number+','+"'"+row.order_code+"'";

        return '' +
          '<ul class="icons-list">' +
          '<li class="dropdown">' +
          '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >' +
          '<i class="icon-menu9"></i>' +
          '</a>' +
          '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
          '<li><a ng-click="open_detail(\'' + type +'\',\'' + row.number +'\')">상세</a>' +
          '<li><a ng-click="deleteDo('+toDeleteStr+')">삭제</a>' +
          '</ul>' +
          '</li>' +
          '</ul>';
      }
    }
  ],

  fnRowCallback: function (nRow) {
    $compile(nRow)($scope);
  }
};
```

2. datatable option

```js
    datatable option
        $scope.grid.dtOptions = {
          "serverSide": true,
          "ajax": {
            "url": settings.apiUrl + "/api/order/shipmentList",
            "data": function ( d ) {
              var data = angular.merge({}, d, $scope.searchForm);
              data.orderby = 'number desc';
              var search_date = data.search_date.split(" ~ ");
              data.sdate = search_date[0];
              data.edate = search_date[1];
    
              return JSON.stringify(data);
            },
            "dataSrc": function(json){
              $scope.status_total = json.status_total;
              $scope.status_map_total = json.map_total;
              $scope.status_total1 = json.status["신규주문"] ? json.status["신규주문"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total2 = json.status["출고대기"] ? json.status["출고대기"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total3 = json.status["보류"] ? json.status["보류"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total4 = json.status["출고완료"] ? json.status["출고완료"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total5 = json.status["배송중"] ? json.status["배송중"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total6 = json.status["수취확인"] ? json.status["수취확인"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total7 = json.status["정산완료"] ? json.status["정산완료"].total:0;
              $scope.status_total8 = json.status["수집완료"] ? json.status["수집완료"].total:0;
              $scope.$apply();
              return json.results;
            }
          },
          "select": true,
          "columns": [
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" },
            { "data": "number" }
          ]
        };
```

3. modal open event

```js
        $scope.open_detail = function (type,number) {
      var data = {};
      data.type = type;
      data.number = number;

      var resolve = {
        data : data
      };

      var modal = commonSVC.openModal("lg", resolve, 'OrderShipmentDetailOrderCtrl', 'views/order/shipment/detail_order.html');
      modal.closed.then(function(){
        $scope.grid.dtInstance.reloadData(function(json){  }, true);
      });
    };
```

Comment: Please show your work. We can't help you fix what we can't see.

Comment: might nd some code to look at if you want the problem diagnosed.

Comment: and a good few word don't write. stackoverflow think it's sapm. so I don't just write question. plz understand thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find reason.
don't use fnRowCallback option.
have to use fncreatedrow